# Can you use the handbreak while Franklin's ability is on?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Can you use the handbreak while Franklin's driving ability is on?

There is a long description on [wikia](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Special_Ability), but nothing talks about the handbreak. When I try, it seems to do nothing.

Comment: Possibly not - and I want to say the reason you can't is because time slows down partially and you can turn much more easily while using Franklin's ability (practically on a dime if I remember right).  I haven't tested for myself though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**. Franklin's driving ability and the handbrake *can* be used in conjunction with one another.

Whether it is effective for precision drifting is a big **no**

I have attempted this maneuver in several cars (the latest being a *Pegassi Zentorno* that ranged from stock to topend across the board), a number of times under several conditions. Each outcome was a stop with the wheels turned like a careful parking job.

So, it can be used technically speaking but doesn't perform the action of putting the car into a slide because of Franklin's ability making it a rather useless combination.